# How to print correctly a linked list with name of persons?

Tags: c++, list, char

I did a code in which I want to print a simple linked list, and the information of the list contain name of person and number phone. Unfortunately, when I print my list have only the name of the last person which I read but the phone numbers were different. I have no idea why my code didn't work.

So, here is my code

```
#pragma once

struct Nodd{
   int phone;
   char *name;
   Nodd *next;
};

void InsertList(Nodd *&L,int nr,char *n);
void PrintList(Nodd *&L);


#include <iostream>
#include "Header.h"
using namespace std;
void InsertList(Nodd *&L,int nr, char *n){
    Nodd *p = new Nodd;
    p->name = n;
    p->phone = nr;
    p->next = L;
    L = p;
}

void PrintList(Nodd *&L){
     Nodd *p = L;
     while(p){
       cout << p->name << " " << p-> phone << endl;
       p = p->next;
     }
}

#include <iostream>
#include "Header.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){

    Nodd *L = 0; //L = first element of the linked list
    int nr, i, t;
    char *n;
    n = new char;

    cout <<"Read number of people: ";
    cin >> t;

    for(i = 0; i < t; i++){
        cout << "Name: ";
        cin.ignore(50, '\n');
        cin.getline(n, 50);

        cout << "Phone number: ";
        cin >> nr;
        InsertList(L, nr, n);
    }

    PrintList(L);

    return 0;
}
```

And what I compiled was:

Read number of people: 2

```
Name: Elena
Phone number: 99776244

Name: Andreea 
Phone number: 98776489
```

............................

```
Andreea  98776489
Andreea  99776244
```

Can you help me how to fix my code?

Comment: Use a debugger or shorten the code to the section that is actually problematic

Comment: `n=new char;` what do. you think this does? Use std::string instead of char*!

Comment: `n=new char;` Allocates only one character on the heap. Use `n=new char;[size]` as I guess what you need here. Also Don't forget to free up memory using `delete[] n` when you're done with it.

Comment: @Raindrop7 that would fix one of many errors. **It's C++. Use the appropriate data structure! Use std::string.**

Comment: @manni66: Yes that's true.

Answer (score 0):

You have many errors in your code:

```
char *n;
n = new char; // A single dynamic character
```

And later:

```
cin.getline(n, 50); UB here
```

as you can see assigning 50 character to a single character variable so it is an undefined behavior.

To correct it:

```
char* n = new char[50];
```

- If you pay deep look to your output what you see:

  Andreea 98776489
  Andreea 99776244

The same name but the integer values are correct! So your inserting nodes function is correct but the problem is about name. Why?

In insert node you write:

```
p->name=n; // That is not the way you should do it.
```

Correct it to:

```
  p->name = new char[strlen(n) + 1];
  strcpy(p->name, n);
```

You have to allocate memory for the member `name` for each node not sharing the same one.

- Also when you're done with dynamic memory you must free up and clean to avoid memory leak:

  ```
  delete[] n;
  ```
- Add a function to free up memory of all nodes for the member name:

  ```
  void FreeupMemory(Nodd*& L){
      Nodd* pTmp = L;
      while(pTmp){
          delete[] pTmp->name;
          pTmp = pTmp->next;
      }
  }
  ```

And in main after printing the nodes data free up memory:

```
      FreeupMemory(L);
```

- What I recommend: As long as C++ offers you many powerful classes and utilities give up using dynamic arrays so here you can use `class string`, `vector`. It is really good and don't mind about memory leak.
- Believe me if your member data `name` was a string class object you wouldn't get stuck in such error-prone.

  ```
  struct Nodd{
      int phone;
      std::string name;
     Nodd *next;
  };

  void InsertList(Nodd *&L,int nr, std::string n){
      // your code
      p->name = n; // ok
      // ...
  }
  ```

In main:

```
    std::string n;
    for(int i(0); i < t; i++){
        std::getline(std::cin, n);
    }
```

** Also there a bad thing:

Why you include the header in itself? "recursive inclusion"?

You can create a header file "header.h" contains only class interface and functions' prototypes and another source file "MyLinkedList.cpp"
 that includes the header. And main.cpp.

```
// header.h
#pragma once

struct Nodd{
   int phone;
   char *name;
   Nodd *next;
};

void InsertList(Nodd *&L,int nr,char *n);
void PrintList(Nodd *&L);
void FreeupMemory(Nodd*&L);


// MyLinkedList.cpp

#include "header.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


void InsertList(Nodd*& L, int nr, char* n){
    Nodd *p  = new Nodd;
    p->name  = n;
    p->phone = nr;
    p->next  = L;
    L = p;
}

void PrintList(Nodd *&L){
    Nodd* p = L;
    while(p){
        cout << p-> name << " " << p->phone << endl;
        p = p->next;
    }
}

void FreeupMemory(Nodd*& L){
    Nodd* pTmp = L;
    while(pTmp){
        delete[] pTmp->name;
            pTmp = pTmp->next;
    }
}

// main.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include "Header.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){
    Nodd* L = 0; //L = first element of the linked list
    int nr, i, t;
    char* n = new char[50];

    cout << "Read number of people: ";
    cin >> t;

    for(int i = 0; i < t; i++){
        cout << "Name: ";
        cin.ignore(1, '\n');
        cin.getline(n, 50);

        cout << "Phone number: ";
        cin >> nr;

        InsertList(L, nr ,n);
    }

    PrintList(L);
    FreeupMemory(L);
    delete[] n;

    return 0;
}
```

- One last thing a good linked list defines functions for adding and deleting nodes as member methods and there should be destructor to free up memory.